# String generation based on the other string in Python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, auto-generate

I want to create a simple string generator and here is how it will work

1. I declare a `pattern_string =  "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"`
2. My starting string lets say `starting_string = "qywtx"`
3. Now I want to generate strings as follows:
4. Check the last character in my `starting_string`against the pattern string.
5. Last character is `x`. We find this character in the find it in the `pattern_string`:

   abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvw **x** yz

   and see that next character is `y` so I want output `qywty`.
   ...

However, when I reach the z, I want my string to increment second last character and set the last character to the first character of the `starting_pattern` so it will be `qywra` and so on...

Now questions:

- Can I use REGEX to achieve that?
- Are there any libraries out there that already handle such generation?

Comment: Shouldn't the order you describe be: `'qywtx' -> 'qywty' -> 'qywtz' -> 'qywua'`?

Comment: Hey @schwobaseggl you are right, I made a typo in my post thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will generate the next string according to your description.

```
def next(s, pat):
  l = len(s)
  for i in range(len(s) - 1, -1, -1):  # find the first non-'z' from the back
    if s[i] != pat[-1]:  # if you find it
      # leave everything before i as is, increment at i, reset rest to all 'a's
      return s[:i] + pat[pat.index(s[i]) + 1] + (l - i - 1) * pat[0]
  else:  # this is only reached for s == 'zzzzz'
    return (l + 1) * pat[0]  # and generates 'aaaaaa'  (just my assumption)

>>> import string
>>> pattern = string.ascii_lowercase  # 'abcde...xyz'
>>> s = 'qywtx'
>>> s = next(s, pattern)  # 'qywty'
>>> s = next(s, pattern)  # 'qywtz'
>>> s = next(s, pattern)  # 'qywua'
>>> s = next(s, pattern)  # 'qywub'
```

For multiple `'z'` in the end:

```
>>> s = 'foozz'
>>> s = next(s, lower)  # 'fopaa'
```

For all 'z', start over with 'a' of incremented length:

```
>>> s = 'zzz'
>>> s = next(s, lower)  # 'aaaa'
```

To my knowledge there is no library function to do that. One that comes close is [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> list(map(''.join, product('abc', repeat=3)))
['aaa', 'aab', 'aac', 'aba', 'abb', 'abc', 'aca', 'acb', 'acc', 'baa', 
 'bab', 'bac', 'bba', 'bbb', 'bbc', 'bca', 'bcb', 'bcc', 'caa', 'cab',
 'cac', 'cba', 'cbb', 'cbc', 'cca', 'ccb', 'ccc']
```

But that doesn't not work with an arbitrary start string. This behaviour could be mimicked by combining it with `itertools.dropwhile` but that has the serious overhead of skipping all the combinations before the start string (which in the case of an alphabet of 26 and a start string towards the end pretty much renders that approach useless):

```
>>> list(dropwhile(lambda s: s != 'bba', map(''.join, product('abc', repeat=3))))
['bba', 'bbb', 'bbc', 'bca', 'bcb', 'bcc', 'caa', 'cab', 'cac', 'cba', 'cbb', 'cbc', 'cca', 'ccb', 'ccc']
```